# How to rewrite functions to perform reset and stop with one button click

Tags: javascript

I tried MANY permutations, but was unable to happen on one that worked...

This is a short script for a Learning/ DEMO page, it is ready to run on your localhost, anybody curious to see it misbehaving.  A double click on the stop button makes it work, but it just seems there must be a way to both stop the loop and reset, with one click.

I have been learning JavaScript for a few weeks only, so wouldn't be surprised if the problem is something simple I am missing.  Here is the offensive code  :)

```
        
        
        MY Loop
        

        //  At window loading, be good to have some .className  
        // set on the DIV elements which require them, so they show up.
        var ScaryMonster = window.onload=function portofOrigin(){
        Div1ne.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        Div2wo.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        Div3hree.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        Div4our.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        Div5iver.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        };
        //  Then go ahead and define a shwack of functions the DIVS will
        //  be manipulated by through the action of the LOOP code.
        // functions:  ItemBar1
        function ItemBar1COLOUR(){
        timeoutIDxDiv1 = window.setTimeout(Div1neDOsomethingDoggoneIt, 160);
        }
        function Div1neDOsomethingDoggoneIt(){
            Div1ne.className = "springME";
        Div2wo.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div3hree.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div4our.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div5iver.className = "defaultBORED";
        }
        // functions:  ItemBar2
        function ItemBar2COLOUR(){
        timeoutIDxDiv2 = window.setTimeout(Div2woDOsomethingDoggoneIt, 320);
        }
        function Div2woDOsomethingDoggoneIt(){
        Div1ne.className = "defaultBORED";
            Div2wo.className = "springME";
        Div3hree.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div4our.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div5iver.className = "defaultBORED";
        }
        // functions:  ItemBar3
            // here the Timer Function is defined for the Item #3 of the set of the Loop
        function ItemBar3COLOUR(){
            // it is set to fire, if called, at 480/800 milliseconds    
        timeoutIDxDiv3 = window.setTimeout(Div3hreeDOsomethingDoggoneIt, 480);
        }
            // This, is the Function which contains the code which  
            // will be run if Item #3 is called.
        function Div3hreeDOsomethingDoggoneIt(){
            // .defaultBORED is the *non~lit~up* state of appearance  
            // of the divs while the loop is running.   
        Div1ne.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div2wo.className = "defaultBORED";
            // while .springME is the *active* display appearance  
            // of the div during "animation loop*
            Div3hree.className = "springME";
        Div4our.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div5iver.className = "defaultBORED";
        }
        // functions:  ItemBar4
        function ItemBar4COLOUR(){
        timeoutIDxDiv4 = window.setTimeout(Div4ourDOsomethingDoggoneIt, 640);
        }
        function Div4ourDOsomethingDoggoneIt(){
        Div1ne.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div2wo.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div3hree.className = "defaultBORED";
            Div4our.className = "springME";
        Div5iver.className = "defaultBORED";
        }
        // functions:  ItemBar5
        function ItemBar5COLOUR(){
        timeoutIDxDiv5 = window.setTimeout(Div5iveDOsomethingDoggoneIt, 800);
        }
        function Div5iveDOsomethingDoggoneIt(){
        Div1ne.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div2wo.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div3hree.className = "defaultBORED";
        Div4our.className = "defaultBORED";
            Div5iver.className = "springME";
        }

        /*        ******************************************    */
        //  This is the BEGIN POINT of the Main Timer Loop To create the faux~animation
        function SetThemUP(){

        // This Function creates a TIMESTAMP anywhere you wish to
        // place one, by calling the function.
        function JustTIMEstamp(){
            var OkayFIRE = +new Date();
           return OkayFIRE;
        }

        //  For Whatever reason this works as a holder for a whole lot of functions
        function wellrelaxCODEworkWITHmeHere(){

        //  The first item in this Function collection, is a TimeStamp.  
        //  Obtained by calling a Function which has code to make one.
        var newOkayFIRE = JustTIMEstamp();

        //  1 of 4 Functions needed to build a friggin' 
.
        //       It is a Function which when called, appends the
        // assembled  LB to the DOM as a child of the target DIV element.
        function SoWriteTimeStampToDivYello(){
            var myDiv1 = document.getElementById("Aaaiyeeah");
            var YellowTitleWrite = myDiv1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newOkayFIRE));
            return YellowTitleWrite;
        }

        //  2 of 4. sic.  it needs to create a discrete html element...  
        //  the one referrenced above.
        function FancyShitForLBWIN1(){
            var compLbr="var inTheLinebreaks";
            var thirdcompOFintheLinebreaks = "=document.createElement('br');";
            var AssembledDocCreateLB=(compLbr+ thirdcompOFintheLinebreaks);
            return AssembledDocCreateLB;
        }

        //  3 of 4. sic. and surprisingly, only works by directly  
        // inserting a line break onto the variable being
        //  cobbled together to provide a recycleable 
 construct...
        function middleware(){
            var myDiv33 = document.getElementById("Aaaiyeeah");
            var inTheLinebreaks7=document.createElement('br');
            myDiv33.appendChild(inTheLinebreaks7);
        }

        //  4 of 4  and the final component for the asset  
        // "reuseable 
" which can be deployed in DIV "Aaaiyeeah" ONLY
        //  but of course, as many times as required, so at least it is useful.
        function FancyShitForLBWIN2wo(){
            var theAppending1stPart="myDiv42.appendChild(";
            var varNameProper=("inTheLinebreaks");
            var fouthPart=");";
            var assembleAppenderHerself=(theAppending1stPart + varNameProper +               fouthPart);
            return assembleAppenderHerself;
        }

        //  Oh, LookitThet, here it is, getting called.  
        //  So, this is inside the wrapper Function, inside the TIMER Loop.
        //  Which has the effect that each time the LOOP gets called,  
        // a record of the TIMESTAMP GO~Time is written out to display.
        SoWriteTimeStampToDivYello();
        FancyShitForLBWIN1();middleware();FancyShitForLBWIN2wo();  //LINEBREAK

        //  wellrelaxCODEworkWITHmeHere() end of function:
        }

        // then call all of em at one shot here:
        wellrelaxCODEworkWITHmeHere();

        // these are the calling of the 5ive functions which are defined OUTSIDE of the       MainTimerLoop; the STEPS or Components,
        // from which the LOOP is assembled.
        ItemBar1COLOUR();
        ItemBar2COLOUR();
        ItemBar3COLOUR();
        ItemBar4COLOUR();
        ItemBar5COLOUR();

        // here is a call to the function in which the call is contained.
        // By Setting the number, the number of milliseconds of the  
        // duration of the Loop Timer, is established.
        //        Therefore
        // In order to have an even event duration, the events have got  
        // to be timed, themselves, in a ratio of their number
        // to the length of time in milliseconds, which the Loop will Occupy.
        CommenceAnnoyance = window.setTimeout(SetThemUP,800);

        // SetThemUP() end of MAIN TIMER Loop :: psuedo~animation
        }
        /*  **********************    */
        /*  *********************************    */




        // Here begins parts of CODE suggested by Gordon.
        // while this is called by the *Reset* button to reset the divs  
        // to their *Loop=OFF* appearance, AND clear the text
        // from the DIV which displays one after another, the  
        // GoTime of the PerLoop Iterations of the MAIN LOOP.
        function DestroyTheMonster() {
            Stop();
            Reset();
            FTWxAnotherReset();   //  that is a kludgy desperation~ploy
                                    // to try to get rid of the unwanted .class
                          //  which is still applied, and to reset all  
                                // 5ive to the NON~running state... appearance.
        }

        // This is the    *** OFF SWITCH ***    for the MainTimerLOOP.
        function Stop() {
            window.clearTimeout(CommenceAnnoyance);
        }


        function Reset() {
            var Aaaiyeeah = document.getElementById('Aaaiyeeah');
              while (Aaaiyeeah.firstChild) {
                Aaaiyeeah.removeChild(Aaaiyeeah.firstChild);
            }
            Div1ne.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div2wo.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div3hree.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div4our.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div5iver.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        }

        function FTWxAnotherReset() {
            var Aaaiyeeah = document.getElementById('Aaaiyeeah');
              while (Aaaiyeeah.firstChild) {
                Aaaiyeeah.removeChild(Aaaiyeeah.firstChild);
            }
            Div1ne.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div2wo.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div3hree.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div4our.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
            Div5iver.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
        }


        


        
        
        

        #TitleGhost{
            position:absolute;
            top:11px;
            left:295px;
            width:496px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:#8ADFFB;
            font-size:19px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-style:italic;
            font-variant:small-caps;
            color:black;
            border:3px solid navy;
            padding-top:3px;
        }   
        #ControlPlace{
            position:absolute;
            top:11px;
            left:19px;
            width:142px;
            height:42px;
            background-color:#33EFEA;
            border:2px solid buttonface;
        }
        #ControlPlace button{
            position:absolute;
            top:6px;
            left:13px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:buttonface;
            font-family:bookman old style;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:navy;
        }
                #ControlPlaceSTOPPA{
            position:absolute;
            top:72px;
            left:19px;
            width:142px;
            height:42px;
            background-color:#33EFEA;
            border:2px solid buttonface;
        }
        #ControlPlaceSTOPPA button{
            position:absolute;
            top:6px;
            left:13px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:buttonface;
            font-family:bookman old style;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:navy;
        }
        #Aaaiyeeah{  /*Displays Unix TimeSTAMP of Each Loop Begin~Time*/
            position:absolute;
            top:11px;
            left:819px;
            width:131px;
            height:430px;
            background-color:#C79C96;    /*  Impious Colours = "the lost art"   */
            color:#A48F04;  /*  Impious Colours = "GoldyGoldfish"   */
            border:2px solid black;
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }
        /* Main Display Box  */
        #BeginLoopingLikeAMadBastard{
        position:absolute;
        top:137px;
        left:295px;
        width:492px;
        height:298px;
        background-color:#333333;
        border:5px solid purple;
        }
        /* 5 Divs In the main display  */
        #Div1ne.defaultBORED{
            position:absolute;
            top:12px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div1ne.springME{
            position:absolute;
            top:12px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div2wo.defaultBORED{
            position:absolute;
            top:61px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div2wo.springME{
            position:absolute;
            top:61px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div3hree.defaultBORED{
            position:absolute;
            top:110px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div3hree.springME{
            position:absolute;
            top:110px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div4our.defaultBORED{
            position:absolute;
            top:159px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div4our.springME{
            position:absolute;
            top:159px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div5iver.defaultBORED{
            position:absolute;
            top:208px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }
        #Div5iver.springME{
            position:absolute;
            top:208px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
        }

        #Div1ne.AsBeforeBubba{
            position:absolute;
            top:12px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:#EEff78;
            border:2px solid #FC3B03;
        }
        #Div2wo.AsBeforeBubba{
            position:absolute;
            top:61px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:#EEff78;
            border:2px solid #FC3B03;
        }
        #Div3hree.AsBeforeBubba{
            position:absolute;
            top:110px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:#EEff78;
            border:2px solid #FC3B03;
        }
        #Div4our.AsBeforeBubba{
            position:absolute;
            top:159px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:#EEff78;
            border:2px solid #FC3B03;
        }
        #Div5iver.AsBeforeBubba{
            position:absolute;
            top:208px;
            left:11px;
            width:112px;
            height:29px;
            background-color:#EEff78;
            border:2px solid #FC3B03;
        }

        /*  defining some .classNames, for some css statements controlled
         by the JavaScript          */
        #Div1ne.springME{
            background-color:forestgreen;
            border:4px solid red;
        }
        #Div2wo.springME{
            background-color:forestgreen;
            border:4px solid red;
        }
        #Div3hree.springME{
            background-color:forestgreen;
            border:4px solid red;
        }
        #Div4our.springME{
            background-color:forestgreen;
            border:4px solid red;
        }
        #Div5iver.springME{
            background-color:forestgreen;
            border:4px solid red;
        }


        #Div1ne.defaultBORED{
            background-color:#333333;
            border:2px solid white;
        }
        #Div2wo.defaultBORED{
            background-color:#333333;
            border:2px solid white;
        }
        #Div3hree.defaultBORED{
            background-color:#333333;
            border:2px solid white;
        }
        #Div4our.defaultBORED{
            background-color:#333333;
            border:2px solid white;
        }
        #Div5iver.defaultBORED{
            background-color:#333333;
            border:2px solid white;
        }

        

        
        
            
        Commence !!!
            
        Stop Madness!
            

          This Is JavaScript.  Looping OR at Least Pretending To.
```

For anyone without their own stack but curious, see

Oh for ... are you SERIOUS ????

See if this works... 
Okay guys, you have a gaping hole in your functionality.  I just spent 45 minutes or an HOUR formatting 450 lines manually, then think to add a link, and get the infamous and annoying Ooops! ANTI~jsfiddle.net bullshit?  Pulllese!  S.O. seems so far above that service, serves a different purpose... lighten up or incorporate a similar feature inhouse; just don't understand the bias against it.  I DO understand the desire to have substantial code ON SITE here at S.O....  but mebbe fine~tune when the backend complains about a link, neh?   *rant over*

Still working the problem... I will not accept having to click twice, once to stop the animation/loop and once to reset the className of the 5 divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of any weird race conditions (due to the `setTimeout`), I don't see any reason why this wouldn't do what you desire...

```
function DestroyTheMonster() {
    Stop();
}

function Takes2woToTaengo() {
    Stop();
    setTimeout("Reset()", 800); // this is the delay
}

function Stop() {
    window.clearTimeout(CommenceAnnoyance);
}

function Reset() {
    var div = document.getElementById('Aaaiyeeah');
      while (div.firstChild) {
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
    }
    Div1ne.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
    Div2wo.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
    Div3hree.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
    Div4our.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
    Div5iver.className = "AsBeforeBubba";
}
```

Comment: Tried a few more permutations, putting some in the main function, all, etc., none...  goal is to just use 1 button, the    onclick="DestroyTheMonster();" >StopMadness< /button >; so far no luck  :\

Comment: Well, the concept is simple. Function decomposition breaks down your code into chunks that can then be called via other functions, without resorting to code duplication. If you want multiple functions to render a "Stop" event, create a `Stop()` function, etc.

Comment: You write *if you want mutiple functions to render a "Stop" event, create a Stop() function/"  Um... what I would like is to get away from that... (I think)... Objective, I will say again, is 1 button click... to do 2 things... your indubitably well intended suggestions are only reproducing for me in a dozen arrangements, the same behaviour I found earlier: one thing happening but not the other.  Function decomposition hmm  like atomization...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am telling you: 1 button click -> 1 function -> calls 2 other functions.

Comment: I updated my answer. I see your problem now. What is happening is that it takes time for "the annoyance" to stop, because of the delay effect from `setTimeout`, therefore, a similar delay is necessary in order to `Stop()` and `Reset()`. I tried this out on your JSFiddle.

Comment: You are exactly right.  I arrived at the same conclusion at around 8 pm. Sunday and by 2 am., (did I mention I am new to JS ~ Ha.) I came up with a solution.  It may be kludge but it works. http://jsfiddle.net/MountainMan72/e5YtS/  I will accept your answer because you got me on the right track with breaking down each bit of functionality and calling them in a *chain* as it were.